# Why my column dont shown under "Add a column to show each of these additional fields"?

Tags: sharepoint, lookup-tables

In SP2010,

I want to get 2 columns from another list and merge these columns. But while i am trying to do this via Lookup, they dont shown under "Add a column to show each of these additional fields".

But i tried simple text one (not lookup) it shown.

Is there anyway to make it shown which is a kind of lookup field  ?

Comment: Has been asked on SharePoint.SE - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39578/why-my-column-dont-shown-under-add-a-column-to-show-each-of-these-additional-fi

Answer (score 1):

Not all fields are supported as lookup fields.  I tried to find a supported fields list but didn't find one.  While searching though I ran across this discussion which offers a fix for columns that aren't supported such as choice fields.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/5a80988a-6b37-4454-957b-856ea16b2e60